# JSP - URL & Parameter Error Logging

Tags: jsp, logging

Is it possible to log the exact URL being accessed and the parameters passed? I have a series of errors being logged from mutiple sites that use the same jsp filename. I can't seem to replicate the server errors on my development box so would like to log as much as I can to try and narrow the issue down.

The error I'm getting is:

```
    01-Mar-2013 21:37:58 org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher invoke
    SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet jsp threw exception
    java.lang.NullPointerException
    at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(FloatingDecimal.java:991)
    at java.lang.Double.valueOf(Double.java:475)
    at org.apache.jsp.product_jsp._jspService(product_jsp.java:212)
```

I can resolve the error if I can figure what is attempting to be accessed, if that makes sense.

Any help would be much appreciated :-)

Comment: Use a logging filter?

Comment: Could you please provide an example? I don't want to create huge log files, just report the full url inclusing domain and parameters when an error is reported.

Comment: I mean, the error is obvious; without knowing how the JSP is being used it's difficult to provide meaningful advice about how to best capture and log the error. If it's entirely within a JSP (ewewew) then catch the exception in the JSP and log the request URL and parameters.

Comment: The error is local to the JSP page itself. I have noticed that various suspect IPs are tring to trawl our sites, the errors appear when certain parameters are not being passed, so I'm trying to replicate the error so that I can fix it.

I dont know how to catch the exception, hence the request.

Comment: You use try/catch... That said, it's pretty poor practice to have Java code in a JSP page.

Answer (score 0):

You could define an error handler page in `web.xml` like this:

```
<error-page>
    <exception-type>java.lang.Exception</exception-type>
    <location>/...</location>
</error-page>
```

and in that page/servlet log original request information. It should be available, because according to Servlet specification

> If the location of the error handler is a servlet or a JSP page:
>
> ■ The original unwrapped request and response objects created by the container are
>   passed to the servlet or JSP page.
>
> ■ The request path and attributes are set as if a RequestDispatcher.forward to the
>   error resource had been performed.

So you could use [getRequestURL()](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getRequestURL%28%29) or other method or any of the request attributes `javax.servlet.error.status_code`, `javax.servlet.error.exception_type`, `javax.servlet.error.message`, `javax.servlet.error.exception`, `javax.servlet.error.request_uri`, `javax.servlet.error.servlet_name`.

to get all the needed info to log.